# Put quotation mark around variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to put quotation marks around my variable if it's not empty.
So I got this in a for loop and want an else statement that put $var in quotation marks if I want to Echo it out later on.
How goes the syntax?

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    eval 'val=$'"$var"
        if [ -z "$val" ]; then
            eval "${var}=null"
        fi
done
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: `myvar2="\"${myvar}\""`

Comment: I updated my code so you can see more.

Comment: Not at all clear why you're doing this; whatever you're trying to actually accomplish can be done more cleanly, but you could simply replace your initial eval with `eval "$var=\${$var:-null}" ` and skip the conditional completely.

Comment: If I had to maintain your script, I'd rather just see 4 similar assignment statements than this kind of "DRY" loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `eval` here at all. Instead, use indirect parameter expansion and the `:=` parameter expansion operator.

```
# Works in 4.4, but not in earlier versions
for var in var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    : ${!var:=null}
done
```

However, I'd find a list of repeated assignments easier to read and maintain (as well as being POSIX-compliant).

```
: ${var1:=null}
: ${var2:=null}
: ${var3:=null}
: ${var4:=null}
```

---

Having forgotten about the quotes, I'd fall back to using `printf` to handle the dynamic assignments.

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 var4; do
  oldVal="${!var}"
  if [ -z "$oldVal" ]; then
    newVal=null
  else
    newVal=\"$oldVal\"
  fi
  printf -v "$var" '%s' "$newVal"
done
```

`printf -v` is safer than `eval`, but it's a `bash` extension. Continue using `eval "$var=..."` (with all the dangers that entails) if you need POSIX compatibility.

Comment: That doesn't address the need to put quotes around the value of the variable if it is not empty though

Comment: Ooops, completely forgot that part.